How to Handle a Discovery after a Masters Completes
I am completing a Masters this week and whilst writing the dissertation, I believe I may have discovered a hitherto unknown data sequence.  At least, I cannot find it documented in the literature.
I mentioned the data sequence in my dissertation but in retrospect, the more I think about it, I think it probably deserves its own journal submission.
My first thought is to ask my supervisor if he would be interested in publishing a paper with me on the topic.
I will be an ex student after this week so there's no financial support for him to continue to assist.
Would it be expected to offer remuneration to my former supervisor to assist or would it be more normal for them to do it as part of their work year if they were interested and a journal article would be of benefit to them?

Congratulations! So, why do you hesitate to bring it to your advisor?

'Would it be expected to offer remuneration to my former supervisor to assist' Absolutely not!

Monetary remuneration? No. Co-authorship? probably, depending on the level of assistance they provide.

You may be correct that it deserves its own publication. I'll assume it is. Your advisor may have something to say about that.
Yes, you can ask your advisor to collaborate on a new paper, or you could do it yourself. Either has advantages. As a masters grad, I'd suggest the collaboration. If it were a doctoral degree it might be a toss up.
If you get a publication, then so does the advisor. That is all the "remuneration" they need or should want. Don't offer to pay them for their collaboration.
In some fields, collaborative work is very highly valued, and that is for all of the collaborators, both senior and junior.
Congratulations.
